# Ports while execution distributed load testing with Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am setting up a distributed load testing scenario using Jmeter.

I have tested that all the ports that are involved (at least in my test case are the following)

**client.rmi.localport=6000 (to get the results from the servers)

server_port=1099 (Jmeter listener in the server)

server.rmi.localport=50000 (port to answer to the client)**

My question is how do the client send the test script to the servers? which port is used? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter will send the [HashTree](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jorphan/collections/HashTree.html) representing your Test Plan on the port which is specified by the `server.rmi.localport` property

The default value is `4000`

More information:

- [DistributedRunner.getClientEngine()](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v5_1_1/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/engine/DistributedRunner.java#L210)
- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)
- [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter/)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. So that means that the machine performing as JMeter-Master needs to have ports assigned both for client.rmi.localport and server.rmi.localport?